# Check Database Table exists or not via Content provider in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-database

As ContentProviders can use internally database,Is there anyway to check particular table exists or not using content provider URI.

Any related links/code helps me a lot.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "As ContentProviders uses internally database" - This isn't true. There's no requirements for a `ContentProvider` to use databases, and I've written them before over `SharedPreferences` or files. They're simply an abstraction layer.

Comment: @PPartisan Thanks for correction. updated the question.

Answer (score -1):

SQL query for checking if a table exists and doing operations:

```
IF 

 (EXISTS

  (SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME)

 )

BEGIN

    --Do Stuff

END
```

Use this query in a cursor and iterate:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( "Your query here" )
```

For more info:

[Content Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics)